# Laravel Sail won't build on Ubuntu 20.04 - groupadd: invalid group ID 'sail'

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to setup a laravel/sail with docker on the fresh ubuntu install.
After following this manual: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-linux

I'm getting an Invalid group ID sail error on sail up (alias has been created so I don't need to use `./vendor/bin/sail up` anymore).

```
groupadd: invalid group ID 'sail'
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

Comment: Can you share the exact steps you took to set up sail,  as well as how you created the alias ?

Comment: @apokryfos `alias sail='bash vendor/bin/sail'` but it doesn't matter, not work with the `./vendor/bin/sail up` as well

Comment: how about the rest of the steps?

Comment: If you are using any tutorial for this, and the tutorial is not working as expected, did you try to contact whoever maintains the tutorial?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem was with the composer itself. After re-installation and clearing docker images it started to build it up!

Comment: I've got that due to running `docker-compose up` directly and not using the `sail up` instead. It seems that the shell script does a lot of additional heavy-lifting. It might be that you've not used `sail` command to do the initial building and that caused some issues.

Answer (score 49):

You can add this to .env file

```
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000
```

Both values should be 1000, but you can also get them from bash

```
id -g <username>
id -u <username>
```

Comment: I've found this to be working solution to the immediate issue but it caused other different problems down the road (of using docker-compose instead of wail wrapper).

Comment: peter.babic, which problems have you found?

Comment: @andrea-matioli permissions related problems, was not able to pin them down exactly yet. I have also posted a short, not very useful comment Github comment [here](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/81#issuecomment-914301837)

Answer (score 12):

You can solve this by running this before making `docker-compose up`:

```
export APP_SERVICE=${APP_SERVICE:-"laravel.test"}
export DB_PORT=${DB_PORT:-3306}
export WWWUSER=${WWWUSER:-$UID}
export WWWGROUP=${WWWGROUP:-$(id -g)}
```

This is something that sail does every time you run a command with it, but when you run docker-compose directly you need to do it before you run commands with sail.

You can see this here: https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/bin/sail#L21

Comment: While it probably solves the issue, the real cause is the direct usage of `docker-compose` instead of `sail` script.

Answer (score 7):

This happens if you run `docker-compose up`, if you run `sail up` it will work as intended.

You might need to configure the alias first:

```
alias sail='bash vendor/bin/sail'
```

Comment: The PHP is not installed on docker host, so it is not possible run `composer install` to dependencies then run sail

Answer (score 2):

I choose to go into the bash of the docker container and 'chown' all the files in www/html/* to 'sail'
First to enter bash for sail.
`sail bash` or `./vendor/bin/sail` if you didn't set up your alias.

Then you should be in the web root `/var/www/html`

```
chown -R sail .
```

That way, you keep the permisions the same as Laravel intended.

Comment: This is literally only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the docker file

```
RUN groupadd --force -g 1000 sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g 1000 -u 1337 sail
RUN chown -R sail:sail /var/www/
```